# Why the minute cronjob configuration in cpanel changed itself

Tags: laravel, cron, queue, cpanel, web-hosting

I have a cronjob configuration that runs once every 3 minutes, as follows

```
*/3     *   *   *   *
```

The command is the artisan queue command in Laravel

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/shalltea/public_html/artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty
```

The problem is, in the first hour after the cronjob configuration is run, the job is executed correctly once every 3 minutes, but when the next hour enters the cronjob minute configuration changes itself to */7, as follows

```
*/7  *  *   *   *
```

I didn't make any configuration changes, it changed by itself. Thankyou

Comment: sounds like a question for your webhosting company

Comment: hmm, it seems so, I'm still waiting for a response from the service provider admin